# Excluding "provided" dependencies from Maven assembly

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I am trying to use the Maven assembly plugin to build a jar-with-dependencies, *except* those that have provided scope.

I have copied the jar-with-dependencies into an assembly.xml file and configured its use in my pom. Here it is for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
  <id>injectable-jar</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I have found out, that if I set the scope to `provided`, then I can build a jar that contains exactly what I *don't* want, but I cannot figure out how to get inverse behavior of that.

Comment: What contains the JAR with the assembly that you shows as example? Does it contains only the runtime dependencies?

Comment: It seems to contain everything but `test`-scoped dependencies.

Comment: No, it also has `test`-scoped dependencies. In what way can that possibly be a sane default, I wonder?

Comment: If you don't use any descriptor, are provided jars included? I think `jar-with-dependencies` don't include provided scope by default.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what behavior you are seeing and what you're wanting. As of v3.6.0, the plugin defaults to [`<scope>runtime</scope>` by default](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet). For me that seems to _exclude_ all dependencies marked with `<scope>provided</scope>`, along with their transitive dependencies, as expected. Is that not the behavior you wanted? Have you tried the latest version of the plugin, currently v3.6.0?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a bit clunky, but you can use the maven-dependency-plugin to copy/unpack all the dependencies into your project, then use the assembly plugin to do the packaging.

The `copy-dependencies` and `unpack-dependencies` goals both have an optional [excludeScope](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeScope) property you can set to omit the `provided` dependencies. The configuration below copies all dependencies into target/lib, your assembly plugin descriptor can be modified to use a [fileSet](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet) to include those jars.

Update: Just tested this to confirm it works. Added the configuration for binding the assembly plugin to the package phase, and the relevant modifications to the assembly descriptor.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-dependencies</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jar-with-deps</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>src/main/assembly/my-assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The fileSet section of the `my-assembly` descriptor would look like this:

```
<assembly>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.*</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
...

</assembly>
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to get it to exclude the one `test` dependency I have, but apart from that it works perfectly. :)

Comment: this is even clunkier, but if you need to exclude the test scope, you could define multiple executions of the dependency plugin, and in each execution specify a different scope to be included (i.e. to omit test and provided, define two executions, one each for <includeScope>compile</includeScope>, and <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>)

Comment: It turns out that one execution is enough. `<includeScope>runtime</includeScope>` is all I need - it implicitly excludes `test`, `provided` and `system`, which is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

In theory the tags "ignoreNonCompile" and "excludeScope" should help, but be warned that they do not necessarily work properly.

With maven3 and the maven-dependency-plugin 2.4, one solution is:

```
<configuration>
<excludeArtifactIds>junit,mockito-all</excludeArtifactIds>
<excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Maven (I was testing on Maven 3.0) this appears to work as expected, with some caveats:

The requested scope (in the dependencySet) may include additional scopes based on the following definition: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Thus, if you request compile scope you will get both compile and provided. However, if you request runtime scope you should get compile and runtime (but not provided).

Comment: Would this feature properly exclude provided dependency if it also happens to belong to runtime transitive dependencies the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but the maven-dependency-plugin now has an "excludeScope" option that you can set to "provided" or whatever scope you need.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#excludeScope

For example,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```