# How to subtract ivy dependency sets

Tags: java, dependencies, gradle, ivy, dependency-management

My goal is to demarcate project transitive dependencies into several not crossing sets:

- system (jars already present in j2ee container; listed manually with explicit fixed versions)
- provided (jars to be copied to j2ee container; listed manually)
- ear (jars to be packed inside ear/lib, the rest)

My current solution listed below has some shortcomings:

- have to exclude system and provided libraries from ear conf one by one
- new third-party transitive deps that weren't already explicitly excluded could accidentally get to ear
- sometimes have to add explicit `override` duplicating library name and version

Is there some approach possible to eliminate these shortcomings?

It would be nice to be able somehow define one conf as a result of dependency sets subtraction of the others (with graceful conflict resolution):
**ear = runtime - system - provided**.

Maybe `<conf name="ear" extends="runtime,!system,!provided"/>` notation could be supported when [IVY-982](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-982) gets fixed.

Looking for an actual solution to apply.

Even willing to consider switching to gradle if it has a solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

    <info organisation="example.com" module="parent"/>

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->@;runtime->@;system->master;provided->runtime;ear->runtime;test->test(default)">
        <conf name="compile"/>
        <conf name="runtime" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="ear" extends="runtime" description="Libs to be packed inside ear"/>
        <conf name="provided" description="Libs to copy to j2ee container"/>
        <conf name="system" description="Libs already present in j2ee container"/>
        <conf name="test" extends="ear,provided,system" description="Simulate container environment. Used by unit tests to catch dependency compatibility problems."/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.15" force="true" conf="system"/>
        <dependency org="commons-collections" name="commons-collections" rev="3.1" force="true" conf="system"/>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.2" force="true" conf="system"/>

        <dependency org="org.apache.velocity" name="velocity" rev="1.7" force="true" conf="provided"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.5.6" force="true" conf="provided"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.5.6" force="true" conf="provided"/>
        <!-- ... -->

        <dependency name="module1" rev="latest.integration" conf="runtime,ear,provided,test"/>
        <dependency name="module2" rev="latest.integration" conf="runtime,ear,provided,test"/>
        <!-- ... -->

        <exclude org="commons-collections" conf="ear,provided"/>
        <exclude org="commons-lang" conf="ear,provided"/>
        <exclude org="org.apache.velocity" conf="ear"/>
        <!-- TODO: negation not working: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-982 -->
        <!--<exclude org="org.slf4j" conf="*, !provided"/>-->
        <exclude org="org.slf4j" conf="ear,test"/>
        <!-- ... -->

        <override org="org.slf4j" rev="1.5.6"/>
        <override org="commons-collections" module="commons-collections" rev="3.1"/>
        <override org="commons-lang" module="commons-lang" rev="2.2"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Sample project sources to experiment with can be found in [IVY-1443](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1443) attachment.

Comment: Please, vote for this comment if you don't know the solution but consider such feature request useful. Silence frightens me. )

Comment: This is how provided exclusion can be done with maven: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459021/excluding-provided-dependencies-from-maven-assembly

Comment: And it seems to be possible with gradle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507215/copy-dependencies-excluding-some-configuration/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While provided dependencies exclusion is possible with [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459021/excluding-provided-dependencies-from-maven-assembly) and [Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507215/copy-dependencies-excluding-some-configuration), it seems that currently there is no way to easily achieve it with ivy.

**Update**

In some cases the task can be worked around with intermediate induced module and [negative regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) mask:

```
    <dependency org="com.company" name="root.module" conf="ear" rev="latest.integration">
        <exclude org="^(?!com.company).*$" matcher="regexp"/>
    </dependency>
```

But we've already moved to Gradle as Ivy seems to be losing momentum.