# Maven: How to have jar-with-dependencies exclude "provided" dependencies?

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have a Maven Scala project that will be deployed on some container and therefore mark several of the dependencies with scope [provided](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) meaning those dependencies will be used for compiling but not taken into account for transitive resolution as they are "provided at runtime". However, when I run the following command, it produces the intended jar with dependencies but also including those dependencies that were marked as `provided`.

```
mvn clean install assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies -DskipTests
```

I tried existing answers to this problem e.g. [Excluding “provided” dependencies from Maven assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459021/excluding-provided-dependencies-from-maven-assembly) but for some reason produces an incorrect choice of dependencies and even missing the main code. In this OP I'd like to find a cleaner, more up to date solution to this problem ... is there one?

Comment: You may be better off with a different maven plugin. See [Difference between maven plugins ( assembly-plugins , jar-plugins , shaded-plugins)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548271/difference-between-maven-plugins-assembly-plugins-jar-plugins-shaded-plugi). [Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) would probably suit you best in this case.

Comment: @JonSampson thank you! it works indeed! Can you please reformat your comment as an answer and I will accept

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I posted a more worthy (I hope) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be better off with a different maven plugin. See [Difference between maven plugins ( assembly-plugins , jar-plugins , shaded-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548271/difference-between-maven-plugins-assembly-plugins-jar-plugins-shaded-plugi). [Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) would probably suit you best in this case. What you are looking to create is referred to an *uber*-jar.

Regarding Shade, from the Maven website:

> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the packages of some of the dependencies.
>
> The goals for the Shade Plugin are bound to the package phase in the build lifecycle.

Configuring Your Shade Plugin:

```
<project>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <!-- put your configurations here -->
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
...
</project>
```

Note that the default implementation replaces your project's artifact with the shade version. Need both? Look here: [Attaching the Shaded Artifact](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/attached-artifact.html)

Merging several jars at once is not necessarily utter simplicity and so Shade has the concept of [Resource Transformers](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html) (link also has more samples).

> Aggregating classes/resources from several artifacts into one uber JAR is straight forward as long as there is no overlap. Otherwise, some kind of logic to merge resources from several JARs is required. This is where resource transformers kick in.

The [project site](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) is actually quite good. There are lots of varied examples.